# Como eliminar carácter estranho em cabeçalho da página

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estranhamente um carácter começou a aparecer no `<body>` de uma página que estou desenvolvendo causando uma linha em branco no layout, mais estranho ainda, pelo que consegui identificar é que se removo a conexão com o meu banco de dados o carácter desaparece.

Como pode ser visto na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A chamada do banco está assim com um select:

```
include_once("_classes/conexao_pdo.class.php");
include_once("_classes/crud.dsc.class.php");

// Instancia Conexão PDO
$conexao = Conexao::getInstance();
$crud = Crud::getInstance($conexao);

// BUSCANDO DADOS DA EMPRESA
$rsEmpresa = "SELECT * FROM empresa WHERE empresa.status = 1";
$stm = $conexao->prepare($rsEmpresa);   
$stm->execute();    
$rsEmpresa = $stm->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
// CONTAGEM DE REGISTROS RETORNADOS
$ContEmpresa = count($rsEmpresa); 
// FECHANDO A CONSULTA
$stm->closeCursor(); 

foreach ($rsEmpresa as $DadosEmpresa) { 
    $historia = $DadosEmpresa->historia;
    $missao = $DadosEmpresa->missao;
    $visao = $DadosEmpresa->visao;
    $valores = $DadosEmpresa->valores;
}
```

A conexão está assim, conexao_pdo.class.php

```
include_once('_connections/config_db.php');

class Conexao {
    /*
     * Atributo estático para instância do PDO  
     */

    private static $pdo;

    /*
     * Escondendo o construtor da classe  
     */

    private function __construct() {
        
    }

    /*
     * Método estático para retornar uma conexão válida  
     * Verifica se já existe uma instância da conexão, caso não, configura uma nova conexão  
     */

    public static function getInstance() {
        if (!isset(self::$pdo)) {
            try {
                $opcoes = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8', PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => TRUE);
                self::$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . HOST . "; dbname=" . DBNAME . "; charset=" . CHARSET . ";", USER, PASSWORD, $opcoes);
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                print "Erro: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$pdo;
    }

}
```

E o config_db.php assim:

```
define('HOST', 'localhost'); 
define('USER', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', ''); 
define('DBNAME', 'banco');
define('TYPEDB', 'mysql'); 
define('CHARSET', 'utf8');
```

Sinceramente não sei o que pode ser.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que possa ser pelo fato de você ter adicionado as tags html de **meta**, **title** etc dentro da tag **body**, quando o correto seria estar dentro da tag **head**.
Na imagem que você postou a tag **head** esta vazia.

Coloca todas tags de title, meta, link etc dentro da tag head e dentro da tag body coloca somente as suas páginas HTML.

Espero ter ajudado.